# How to prevent tinyMCE editor to be loaded completely in Text Editor?

Tags: themes, tinymce

I'm working on a theme. Part of which there are editing modes:

- Syntax-new mode using CodeMirror
- the two native modes (Visual and Text editor)

I have an odd scenario that tinyMCE is loaded on text editor, so that means the buttons, etc. resembles like the Visual editor.

Is there a WP hooks that I can use to prevent it from loading completely in the text editor?
I only need to use the native Text area without these tinyMCE functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working for me:

```
//Sets HTML as default editor
add_filter('wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "html";'));
```

When the page is loaded, it will always use text editor as default, removing extraneous buttons for tinyMCE.